# recvfrom function returns -1 with no error

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp, winsock

The title pretty much says it all. I have a receiving thread waiting for input from a client, but when nothing is read, instead of returning 0 bytes read, it returns -1 yet no errors are returned.

Any hints has to why this function would behave like that?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the receiving code

```
sockaddr_in remote;
remote.sin_family = AF_UNSPEC;
remote.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( _host.c_str() );
remote.sin_port = htons( atoi( _port.c_str() ) );
int remoteSize = sizeof(remote);

bytesRead = recvfrom(_os.socket, 
    (char*)buffer, 
    bufferSize, 
    0,(SOCKADDR*)&remote, &remoteSize);

_error = WSAGetLastError();
```

When I'm executing, `bytesRead` is -1 and `_error` is 0.

Comment: How are you determining that no error is returned?

Comment: `WSAGetLastError` is your friend in this situation. A value of 0 would have meant that the connection was closed. Any value > 0 is the number of bytes read. Invoke `WSAGetLastError()` to determine the cause.

Comment: `-1` is the value of `SOCKET_ERROR`, which is returned from `recvfrom()` when a failure occurs. Use `WSAGetLastError()` to determine reason for failure.

Comment: Any reasons why you are using WinSock directly, instead of Boost.Asio?

Comment: I'm using WinSock due to company requierment

Comment: @nevero, then convince your superior to use Boost. For any serious project (and serious company...) you should be using Boost anyway - and it would be **far** simpler than using winsock (or any other underlying API) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WSAGetLastError()` should not be returning 0 when `recvfrom()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR`.  That would suggest you are probably doing something in between the two calls that indirectly clears WinSock's error code before you can read it.

On a side note, you do not need to fill in the `sockaddr_in` before calling `recvfrom()`.  It fills in the `sockaddr_in` for you with information about the sender.  Whatever information `recvfrom()` needs to perform is job is obtained from the `SOCKET` handle instead.

Comment: As a matter of fact I had code running simultaneously which was accessing the data, turns out it cleared my buffer hence giving the error

Answer (score 2):

One other thing you can try is calling [`getsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SO_ERROR` to check *socket-specific* error (vs. last error on any of the thread's sockets).

Comment: Maybe the socket handle is invalid?